# Checking variable contents

Tags: postman

I have a huge block of test code in postman.
It contains many variables, objects, arrays that are modified while running a test.
In the middle of that, I need to check what is exactly inside one of them.
How do I do that?

Comment: `console.log(pm.variables.get('var_name'))` ? In the right places.

Comment: `console.log` works perfect, I didnt even realize the console is there. Thank you a lot!